# Xscreensaver daemon not set to zero

Tags: 11.10

my problem is that everytime i start ubuntu the monitor goes into stand by. But if i go and choose a screen saver (my screensaver is starfish) it says xscreensaver daemon is not set to zero would you like to set it to zero. I hit yes and the problem is fixed. How can i keep this a permanent setting so that I don't have to keep going to screensaver and changing it?

If it helps my computer is a dell dimension 2350, 2.4 GHz cpu 2GB of ram and an ATI radion x1300 graphics card. 13.9 GB hard drive with ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `xscreensaver -nosplash` in your startup applications?

If not try to add and see if it fixes your problem.